# Do mutes persist between games?

Tags: dota-2

If I mute someone in a public matchmaking game in DotA 2 (from the in-game menu, clicking the microphone button to make it red), will this persist into other DotA 2 games?

Comment: You mean from dota 2 to portal 2, for example? I doubt so.... this doesn't make a lot of sense, since different games are different and behaviour of people as well.

Comment: Given @enche's use of "game" in "public matchmaking game," it seems like they're referring to future Dota 2 matches.

Comment: @cloudymusic is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you are muted by someone, you will be muted from their perspective when you meet again.  It works the other way as well!  If you mute someone during a game, they will be muted until you physically unmute them.  It is persistent across all matches.

Comment: I can confirm this. I've been grouped with someone I both muted and blocked before in ranked matches. The mute persists. (Giving a *very* confusing first 10 minutes of the second game, trying to figure out whom my other 3 teammates were talking to.)

Answer (score 1):

They do in all of Valve's other multiplayer games, so I'm going to assume Yes until presented evidence otherwise.

Comment: By "persist into other games" I'm assuming you mean other DOTA2 matches as opposed to say, mutes from DOTA2 carrying over to CS:GO.

Comment: I can confirm that they do; I've gone into games where another player was already muted due to my doing so in a previous game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it persists into future matches.
Also as I recall you could leave the game without getting an abandon(A.K.A. dodging a player). Although they fixed it because of abuses :p